# How to expand all directories in Projects window in netbeans

Tags: search, user-interface, netbeans, shortcut

I want to expand all directories in Projects window in netbeans.

Why? Because when I click on the project root, and start typing to search the files, it only searches through files of open directories.

If you right click in the projects window, you can see Collapse All, but no Expand All.

Anyone know a shortcut or button somewhere. Or an alternate method of searching all files by filename without expanding all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still don't know how to expand all, but don't need to.

To search through all files by filename in netbeans, use shortcut:

ALT + SHIFT + O